# SSRS Report : Download as excel/pdf instead of rendering in report manager

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

Is it possible to directly download reports in excel/pdf format instead of rendering while viewing in Report Manager?

Comment: Locate the url for downloading the report then add the parameter Format=PDF.

Comment: Our requirement to view it in report manager, to use url we need to pass other report parameters with url that is not allowed in our case.

Comment: You can pass parameters like this: Format=`PDF&para1=var1&para2=var2` etc

Comment: yes we have already proposed this solution but we have to find a way to download in excel/pd format while providing parameters via report manager.

Comment: Isn't there a button that says "download as pdf" or "download" when you've inserted the parameters in report manager?

Comment: yes, but  that shows up after rendering, our reports are taking too much time to render that's why we want to bypass rendering and directly download them.

Comment: Then I don't see any solution other than sending everything into a URL and download it. Is your query slow? What happens if you run the query in your standard database client?

Comment: No, query is not slow only rendering is taking time, even excel download is fast if we pass url.

Comment: Then I don't see any other solution then using an url. You could build your own interface that creates the url though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, read this article on MSDN for further information:
[MSDN Export a Report Using URL Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154040.aspx)

Comment: actually our requirement to view it in report manager, to use url we need to pass other report parameters with url that is not allowed in our case.

Comment: If you don't use the url then you will still need to Generate it first in Report Manager in order to pass in the parameters. After rendering / generating you can export. The only way around this is to use the URL access either directly or through a web front end